# Thermostat hookup / wiring + Nest

Tags: hvac, nest

I have a heat pump system with 5 wires on the thermostat where the yellow and white are tied together (and this system has been working fine for 2+ years).  Couple questions about this setup:

1)  Why are the white and yellow wires tied together?

2)  I'm trying to hook up a Nest (3rd gen).  Its terminals only take 1 wire. Support wasn't much help and told me that my current setup is wrong and the white/yellow wires should not be tied.  How do I switch to the Nest setup properly?

picture of old setup (which is working fine):

[image]

Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Check the other end at the furnace, give us the names of the terminals the wires are connected to.  It sounds like standard color codes where not used.

Comment: @Tyson  Thanks for the reply.  I'll have to hunt down the other end and get back to you with that info.